# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in switch C#

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I have error in switch instruction, but I don't know why. Look at the Main class:

```
            try {  
            var result = string.Join(" ",File.ReadAllBytes(args[0]).Select(x => x.ToString("X")));
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            ASM asm = new ASM(); 
            if(result != null) asm.EXEC(result); //Error here?
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

And ASM class. I think error in EXEC method and in switch-case instruction:

```
public class ASM
{
    public void EXEC(string ex) 
    {
        if (ex == null)
            Console.WriteLine("ASM opcode is null!");
        string[] a = ex.Split(' ');
        int i = 0;
        while (i<a.Length)
        {
            switch (a [i])
            {
                case "AF":  //hlt
                    Environment.FailFast("hlt");
                    break;
                case "AB":  //Write
                    i++;
                    string memorySegment = a[i];
                    i++;
                    int memoryValue = Convert.ToInt32(a[i]);
                    if(memorySegment == "F0") Memory.Write("0xC00",memoryValue);
                    else if (memorySegment == "F1") Memory.Write("0x100",memoryValue);
                    else if (memorySegment == "F2") Memory.Write("0x200",memoryValue);
                    else if (memorySegment == "F3") Memory.Write("0xA00",memoryValue);
                    else if (memorySegment == "F4") Memory.Write("0xB00",memoryValue);
                    break;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
```

In Console I see `AB F1 19 AF
Object reference not set to an instance of an object` How to away this error? Code successfully write the hex code of file, but arguments for ASM.EXEC method (result) not null, but not readable for method. Thanks, sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Provide a stacktrace... `Console.WriteLine(ex);`

Comment: you are trying to convert `AF` or `AB` into Int32. i.e  `int memoryValue = Convert.ToInt32(a[i])`. Error must be here

Comment: `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at asd.Memory.Write (System.String address, Int32 value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at asd.ASM.EXEC (System.String ex) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at asd.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 `

Comment: Do not catch the exception, if you do it like this, most of the exception information is lost.

Remove the try-catch and let the IDE bring up the exception when it occurs. This will give you the additional information (like the linennumer) needed to track down the error more easily.

Comment: @ManishMishra, hex code of file: AB F1 19 AF

Comment: The exception appears to come from inside the `Memory.Write(string, int)` method. What is `Memory.Write`?

Comment: I agree with @JeppeStigNielsen - given the data specified, it must be inside one of `Memory.Write()` methods. A stack trace would probably explain all.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure that this is the reason of the exception, however I should point you to the fact that inside the `case "AB"` you increment the value of `i` without checking if the new value is still inside the bounds of the array a.

If you hit the `AB` case as last byte of your array you have an exception (though it should be IndexOutOfRange exception).